# How to use this Grid adapter constructor

Tags: java, android

I got this adapter from a website as a code snippet but I'm not really sure how to call it in main class of my program.

Snippet:

```
public MonthAdapter(Context c, int month, int year, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
   mContext = c;
   mMonth = month;
   mYear = year;
   mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(mYear, mMonth, 1);
   mCalendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
   mDisplayMetrics = metrics;
   populateMonth();
}
```

Main:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);  
gridview.setAdapter(new MonthAdapter(null, 0, 0, null ));
```

I am not sure about the arguments for `MonthAdapter`, if someone could help me I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Context you can pass the Activity's instance like SomeScreen.this or `getParent().`

for month and year it depends on what you do with that in the adapter. Give us more details on what is your intention of using the adapter.

for metrics you can pass like

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

But definetely don't pass **null**.

Comment: Really dont get the metrics part - "metrics" cannot be resolved :/

Comment: android.util.DisplayMetrics is a structure describing general information about a display, such as its size, density, and font scaling.

For example the following snippet would give the screen resolution. 
We can also find the device density like HDPI, MDPI or LDPI. By using the Constants in this class.
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        String str_ScreenSize = "The Android Screen is: "
                    + dm.widthPixels
                    + " x "
                    + dm.heightPixels;